# get the particular values in a one column based on the value in other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns and I would like to get the values of column `shipping_req_key` based on one `pick_order'. The dataframe looks like this :

```
shipping_req_key      pick_order

5029338170            480280603713
5029338145            480280712615
5029338145            480280804414  
5029338145            480280807715
```

I would like to get the `shipping_req_key` corresponding to the particular `pick_order`. I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I have tried a for loop

Comment: `df[df['pick_order']=='480280603713']` for instance

Comment: or something like `df.query('pick_order==480280603713')`

Comment: @wwnde How can use a for loop here without just giving a particular `pick_order` case you mentioned?

Comment: Loop not necessary unless you have a predifined selection criteria. What set of values do you want to pick in each loop?

Comment: @wwnde the 'pick_order` can have multiple values of`shipping_req_key`. I am doing some operations on those `shipping_req_keys`.  So for each `pick_order` I need to get `shipping_req_key` and do some operation. I have to do this for many `pick_order`

Comment: for that purpose you can use `np.where()` method or use `apply()` method with custom or anonymous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter for all pick_orders try this. Assuming you should store the corresponding order id.

```
pick_list = df.pick_order.unique()

for order in pick_list:
    print(order, df[df['pick_order']==order]['shipping_req_key'].to_list())
```

For particular

```
df[df['pick_order']=='480280603713']
```